# Error de servidor en la aplicación / archivo origen Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

Les presento mi problema que tengo hace rato. Busque varias soluciones y nada. Hago correr el proyecto después de un tiempo me tira este `error` y se me cierra el `visual`. ALGUNA IDEA? DESDE YA MUCHAS GRACIAS

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. Error del analizador
>   Descripción: Error al analizar el recurso requerido para dar servicio
>   a esta solicitud. Revise los detalles de error de análisis específicos
>   y modifique el archivo de código fuente en consecuencia.
>
> Mensaje de error del analizador: No se pudo cargar el tipo
>   'ImportarExcel.Global'.
>
> Error de código fuente:
>
> Línea 1:  `<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs"
>   Inherits="ImportarExcel.Global" Language="C#" %>`
>
> Archivo de origen: `/global.asax`    Línea: 1
>
> Información de versión: Versión de Microsoft .NET
>   Framework:`4.0.30319`; Versión ASP.NET:`4.7.3160.0`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías añadir una captura del error?

Comment: verifica si a donde apunta `Inherits="ImportarExcel.Global"` no le cambiaste el espacio de nombre o el nombre de la clase, si es asi debes de modificar `Inherits`

Comment: Y esa linea1 donde la encuentro? en el  archivo global.asax.cs no me aparece eso!

Comment: Click derecho sobre el archivo Global.asax y seleccione `view Markup` o `ver marcado`

Comment: Gracias orlando! pero no el Inherits esta bien redireccionado. corre un tiempo el programa hago unas cuantas funcionalidades y luego de la nada me sigue saltando ese error